# What is the use of /dev/zero in ELF files?

Tags: unix, elf

The [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/zeros.html) states that

> In addition to all the above, /dev/zero is needed by ELF (Executable and Linking Format) UNIX/Linux binaries.

However I cannot find documentation about such dependency anywhere.

Actually I was unable to find it into the ELF loaders of the Linux kernel too.

Do such dependency still exists? And if so, how is `/dev/zero` used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And if so, how is /dev/zero used?

Before `MAP_ANONYMOUS` was common, `/dev/zero` was used to get a set of zeroed out pages (for the `.bss` section).

But now it's just `mmap(..., MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0)`, and `strace /bin/date |& grep zero` shows no output (i.e. `/dev/zero` is *not* used at all).